# Output directive - bind by context

Tags: angular, nebular

I would like to use `@Output()` but in such non standard scenario that I can't use angular syntax `(somethingChanged)="console.log($event)"` but I have to this that way by binding to context:

```
<nb-icon
   [nbPopover]="messagesComponent"
   [nbPopoverContext]="{ messages: downloadedMessages, onLoadMoreMessages: ??????}"
   >
</nb-icon>
```

so my child component looks like:

```
export class MessagesComponent {
    @Input() messages: Message[];
    @Output() onLoadMoreMessages = new EventEmitter<Message[]>();
    
    someMethod() {
       ...
       this.onLoadMoreMessages.emit(...);
    }
}
```

How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass anything as input e.g. whole parent component... That is a bit weird though, so pass some wrapper (e.g. similar approach is used in angular material: FormControl is passed to input):

```
class MyWrapper {
  subject = new Subject();
  emit() {
    this.subject.next();
  }
}
```

in parent:

```
this.onLoadHandler = new MyWrapper();
this.onLodaHandler.subject.subscribe(() => ...)

<nb-icon
   [nbPopover]="messagesComponent"
   [nbPopoverContext]="{ messages: downloadedMessages, onLoadHandler: onLoadHandler}"
   >
</nb-icon>
```

and in child then you have:

```
someMethod() {
   ...
   this.onLoadHandler.emit(...);
}
```